# toggle inputCheckbox in Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputcheckboxes

My requirement is to check/uncheck a inputcheckbox as and when i press a button. it works fine for the first time. however, after that no matter how many times i click the button, the checkbox doesnt gets checked/unchecked.

I have used an boolean attribute and i set the value of the checkbox with that attribute on click of a button.

here is my component:

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="checkThis" type = "Boolean" default ="true" />
  <ui:button label="press me" press="{!c.changeCheckBox}" />
  <ui:inputcheckbox label="checkBox" value="{!v.checkThis}" />
</aura:component>
```

here is my controller

```
({
changeCheckBox : function(component, event, helper) {
    var getAttributeValue = component.get("v.checkThis");
    if(getAttributeValue=="true"){
        component.set("v.checkThis","false");
    }
    else{
        component.set("v.checkThis","true");
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Try setting the default value to "false" and see if that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've specified the data type as Boolean, I'm pretty sure you need to use native Boolean values. Try this version:

```
({
    changeCheckBox : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.checkThis", !component.get("v.checkThis"));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sticking the following JavaScript alert in your controller after you set getAttributeValue, you will find that it returns false:

```
alert(getAttributeValue=="true"); // false
```

This is because you've declared your `checkThis` attribute as a Boolean type, not a String type. A JavaScript boolean represents two values: true or false. A string stores a sequence of characters, like "blue" or "768 Main Street" or "false". A boolean `false` is not the same as a sequence of characters that make up the word `"false"`:

```
"false" == false // false
"false" == true  // also false
```

Since `checkThis` is a Boolean, you want to compare it to a Boolean value. So taking out all the quotes around all of your true/false values (changing them from string values to boolean values) fixes it:

```
({
changeCheckBox : function(component, event, helper) {
    var getAttributeValue = component.get("v.checkThis");
    if(getAttributeValue==true){
        component.set("v.checkThis", false);
    }
    else{
        component.set("v.checkThis", true);
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks Bro! This fixed the code. however, i still couldnt understand why its not working with the quotes? Can you elaborate on this please? what difference does it make if i include or exclude quotes?

Comment: I updated to hopefully make it clearer. Let me know if it's still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this in javascript, but I have in a apex controller so the logic should be translatable, and this is what I do for my controllers re rendering of check boxes

```
({
changeCheckBox : function(component, event, helper) {
var getAttributeValue = component.get("v.checkThis");
if(getAttributeValue == "false"){
    component.set("v.checkThis","true");
}
else{
    component.set("v.checkThis","false");
    }
}
})
```